# PHP remove exact match and any number from string

Tags: php, regex

How would I go about removing just "hand #X" from this string

```
$text = " 
Hand #1

text Hand #146822299460:

Hand #2

text Hand #146822236378: 


Hand #3

text Hand #346822217642:

Hand #10";
```

the will string have to become this:

```
text Hand #146822299460:



text Hand #146822236378: 




text Hand #346822217642:
```

im writeing this because stackoverflow say's it contans to much code

Comment: @andrew that the opposite of what I want it to do I need to delete Hand #1 Hand #2  Hand #3 and Hand #10

Comment: @chris85 I've edited the post to show the output I wanted

Comment: @gus sorry I was confused, I will delete my above comment

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should work:

```
$text = " 
Hand #1

text Hand #146822299460:

Hand #2

text Hand #146822236378: 


Hand #3

text Hand #346822217642:

Hand #10";
echo preg_replace('/^Hand\h+#\d+\s*$/m', '', $text);
```

Output:

> text Hand #146822299460:
>   
>   
>   text Hand #146822236378: 
>   
>   
>   
>   text Hand #346822217642:

PHP Demo: https://eval.in/501402
Regex101 Demo: https://regex101.com/r/dS7rW7/1

Answer (score -1):

Use [`preg_replace`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-replace.php)

```
echo preg_replace("/^(Hand\s#\d+)/", "", $text);
```

Output:

```
text :



text : 




text :
```

Assuming you only want to remove the lines where "hand #X" is at the beginning of the string, then use

```
echo preg_replace("/^(Hand\s#\d+)/m", "", $text);
```

Comment: Warning: preg_replace(): No ending delimiter '^' found

Comment: it doesn't change the text at all

Comment: Make sure to add in `m` after the last `/`. Last update.